# como setar o valor maximo que uma coluna pode ter com Google Charts

Tags: google-charts

Tenho um Gráfico comparativo entre a nota do aluno e a média da turma, mas queria que o valo do eixo Y sempre fosse 100 e o mínimo 0.

Comment: Possível resposta para sua pergunta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755517/max-and-min-values-on-google-charts).

Comment: @Henrique vlw cara era isso mesmo.

Comment: Bem vindo Rodrigo. Poste o código do seu gráfico usando o google chats que será mais fácil encontra ajuda. Vejo que já conseguiu a resposta que queria, mas é interessante postar para pessoas que tenham a mesma dúvida se orientem melhor. Quando tiver um tempinho, faça o [tour] e conheça melhor a comunidade.